# converting emf image to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

I have a single threaded code to convert emf to BufferedImage to png. So I expect all runs of the code to result in exactly same png for a given input. But my png's vary slightly mostly along the thin shape paths (look at the third chart in images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5yfm.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq4b4.png)).

Comment: Can you show (the relevant part of) the code you use to do this, and also provide a sample EMF file? Along with showing the variations in an attached picture, as that will make it easier for the rest of us to understand the problem. :-)

Comment: I have added pictures, but won't be able to add code snippets due to legal reasons.